# How can I disconnect a button clicked signals in PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qpushbutton

I'm using Qt Designer and PySide2 to create a desktop app. I used PyQt5 before, but had to switch to the PySide2.

And I get this type of error when I try to disconnect a button (which worked fine using PyQt5):

code:
`self.ui.pushButton.disconnect()`

error:
`PySide2.QtCore.QObject.disconnect(): not enough arguments`

What should I add? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mby this will help:

```py
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.disconnect()
```

Hope this can slove your problem :)